# Galaxy A3 (2016) broken screen access files

Tags: backup, usb, data-recovery, broken-screen, files

I have a Samsung Galaxy A3 (2016) - SM-A310F - with a broken screen from a friend to try to backup the files on it. Touch doesn't work and you can't see anything, but I can unlock it with the home button, since no lock screen code is set.

When I connect it to the computer I can't access any files. Samsung Kies says that the device is locked and I should unlock it, even though it is unlocked. I think this is because the device is in charge only mode. USB debugging is disabled so I can't access the phone via adb.

I already checked the [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), but didn't find any solution which helps in my case. I can't access via adb, fastboot doesn't work, too. And I can't install CWM/TWRP because an option is disabled in settings :/